# How to use prepared and bound statement in SQL query

Tags: php, oop, mysqli, prepared-statement

I have been told that my query below is very susceptible to an sql injection - I should be using bound parameters instead,

```
class search
{

    public $mysqli = null;

    public function __construct($mysqli,$keyword = null)
    {
       $this->mysqli = $mysqli;
    }

    public function get_result($parameter)
    {
        $sql = "
        SELECT *
        FROM root_contacts_cfm
        WHERE root_contacts_cfm.cnt_id = '".$parameter."'
        ORDER BY cnt_id DESC
        ";

        $item = $this->mysqli->fetch_assoc($sql);
        return $item;
    }
}
```

can I ask - how can I turn this `search` class with a prepared and bound statement?

I have read some articles online why we should use prepared statements,
[article 1](http://www.adamsinfo.com/php-mysql-developer-using-mysqli-prepared-statements-to-avoid-sql-injection/)
[article 2](http://forum.codecall.net/php-tutorials/12442-php-5-mysqli-prepared-statements.html)

But I still don't have a clue how to improve my query... I tried with this amendment below,

```
class search
{

    public $mysqli = null;

    public function __construct($mysqli)
    {
       $this->mysqli = $mysqli;
    }

    public function get_result($parameter)
    {
        $sql = "
        SELECT *
        FROM root_contacts_cfm
        WHERE root_contacts_cfm.cnt_id = '?'
        ORDER BY cnt_id DESC
        ";

        $stmt = $this->mysqli->prepare($sql);

        /* bind parameters for markers */
        $stmt->bind_param("s", $parameter);

        /* execute query */
        $stmt->execute();

         /* fetch value */
        return $stmt->fetch();

    }
}
```

So when I call the search class as an object,

```
$mysqli = new database(DB_HOST,DB_USER,DB_PASS,DB_NAME);
$output = new search($mysqli);
print_r($output->get_result('1'));
```

I will get this error,

> Warning: mysqli_stmt::bind_param()
>   [mysqli-stmt.bind-param]: Number of
>   variables doesn't match number of
>   parameters in prepared statement in
>   C:\wamp\www\xxxl\class_database.php on
>   line 487

line 487 refers to `$stmt->bind_param("s", $parameter);`

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried using 'd' instead of 's' ?

Comment: @damien: just tried with the 's' but still getting the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try removing `'`, which surrounds your `?` placeholder.

```
$sql = "
SELECT *
FROM root_contacts_cfm
WHERE root_contacts_cfm.cnt_id = ?
ORDER BY cnt_id DESC
";
```

In prepared statements whole thing is about specifying type of param when you bind it, not in SQL query - which you did, when wrote `'?'` . You've said that has to be string, but is not required, when you bind param as a string. Database engine will now how to insert/escape that value.

Comment: thanks. it now returns 1 instead of fetching and returning data from the query...

Comment: `fetch` method will work, if you bound result parameters, which you didn't - look [here](http://pl.php.net/manual/pl/mysqli-stmt.fetch.php). I think, it should be [`fetch_array`](http://pl.php.net/manual/pl/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php) or similar. Look at the examples at PHP.net.

Answer (score 0):

this is my solution after searching around online:

```
class search
{
    public $mysqli = null;

    public function __construct($mysqli)
    {
       $this->mysqli = $mysqli;
    }

    public function get_result($parameter)
    {
        $sql = "
        SELECT *
        FROM root_contacts_cfm
        WHERE root_contacts_cfm.cnt_id = ?
        ORDER BY cnt_id DESC
        ";

        # create a prepared statement
        $stmt = $this->mysqli->prepare($sql);

        # bind parameters for markers
        $stmt->bind_param("s", $parameter);

        # execute query 
        $stmt->execute();



        /*
        # these lines of code below return multi-dimentional array, similar to mysqli::fetch_all()
        $stmt->store_result();

        $variables = array();
        $data = array();
        $meta = $stmt->result_metadata();

        while($field = $meta->fetch_field())
            $variables[] = &$data[$field->name]; // pass by reference

        call_user_func_array(array($stmt, 'bind_result'), $variables);

        $i=0;
        while($stmt->fetch())
        {
            $array[$i] = array();
            foreach($data as $k=>$v)
                $array[$i][$k] = $v;
            $i++;
        }

        return $array;
        */

        # these lines of code below return one dimentional array, similar to mysqli::fetch_assoc()
        $meta = $stmt->result_metadata(); 

        while ($field = $meta->fetch_field()) { 
            $var = $field->name; 
            $$var = null; 
            $parameters[$field->name] = &$$var; 
        }

        call_user_func_array(array($stmt, 'bind_result'), $parameters); 

        while($stmt->fetch()) 
        { 
            return $parameters;
            //print_r($parameters);      
        } 

        # the commented lines below will return values but not arrays
        # bind result variables
        //$stmt->bind_result($id); 

        # fetch value
        //$stmt->fetch(); 

        # return the value
        //return $id; 

        # close statement
        $stmt->close();
    }
}
```

not quite understand it though...

I find it difficult to understand and practice with prepared and bound statement... mysqli::query() is easier for me to understand...